# RenderToBitmap trouble in WPF

Tags: wpf, rendertargetbitmap

Actually, I have to print the view from a `Viewport3D`, obviously, I use a `RenderTargetBitmap`. The problem is that if the resolution of the rendered image got high, some triangles of my scene don't appear on my final image.

For example, my `viewport` can be **1024*768** and the resolution I use with my `RenderTargetBitmap` would be 3 times `viewport`'s resolution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjvgZ.jpg

I already solved the problem in a certain way... In fact, triangles don't appear when I use a big scale. If I lower the size of my `RenderTargetBitmap`, it will contain everything.

Actually, I have more or less **1024*768** at **96dpi**. If I want to impress at **300dpi**, I need to get a huge image so I would like to avoid this last solution.

Some code :

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap CaptureEcran(Viewport3D p_viewPort, int p_scale)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap l_bmp;
        p_scale = p_scale > 5 ? 5 : p_scale;
        l_bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(p_scale * Convert.ToInt32(p_viewPort.ActualWidth), p_scale * Convert.ToInt32(p_viewPort.ActualHeight), p_scale * 96.0, p_scale * 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext dc = vis.RenderOpen();
        dc.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, p_scale * p_viewPort.ActualWidth, p_scale * p_viewPort.ActualHeight));
        dc.Close();

        l_bmp.Render(vis);
        p_viewPort.UpdateLayout();
        l_bmp.Render(p_viewPort);
        return l_bmp;
    }

public static void SaveImage(RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap, string m_impression)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog l_fBD = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        l_fBD.ShowDialog();
        string l_path = l_fBD.SelectedPath + "\\" + CurrentUser() + "__" + CurrentDate() + "__." + m_impression.ToLower();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(l_path, FileMode.Create);

        BitmapEncoder l_encoder = null;
        switch(m_impression){
            case "PNG":
                PngBitmapEncoder l_png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                l_encoder = l_png;
                break;
            case "JPEG":
                JpegBitmapEncoder l_jpeg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                l_jpeg.QualityLevel = 30;
                l_encoder = l_jpeg;
                break;
        }
        l_encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
        l_encoder.Save(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

My call is :

```
SaveImage(CaptureEcran(m_viewPortCourant.ViewPort3D,5), m_impression);
```

Where m_impression is .png or .jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works by using a VisualBrush containing the viewport and drawn into the DrawingContext.

```
DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext dc = vis.RenderOpen(); 
VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(p_viewPort);

dc.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, p_viewPort.ActualWidth * p_scale, p_viewPort.ActualHeight * p_scale));
dc.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), new Vector(p_viewPort.ActualWidth, p_viewPort.ActualHeight)));
dc.Close();    

l_bmp.Render(vis);
```